# problems generating sha with keytool for ionic app

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework, sha

Im trying to generate sha to use facebook plugin and I tried to creat with severals tutorial but I cant do it, letme put the error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Gaston\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
Nombre de Alias: androiddebugkey
Fecha de Creación: 23 feb. 2016
Tipo de Entrada: PrivateKeyEntry
Longitud de la Cadena de Certificado: 1
Certificado[1]:
error de herramienta de claves: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4331)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2846)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2800)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2581)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2517)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2747)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.withWeak(Main.java:3151)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.printX509Cert(Main.java:3182)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintEntry(Main.java:1995)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1212)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem wit java 8 and key tool so you need to force the language and it works:

```
keytool -J-Duser.language=en -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Gaston/.android/debug.keystore -list -v -storepass android
```